# Copy Word table to Excel without splitting cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm struggling to paste a word table into excel without the deliminator splitting out by paragraph, as I want to grabs those paragraphs and paste into excel later.

Does anyone know how to prevent excel from splitting paragraphed text when it is pasted into excel from a word table?

```
Sub InputDoc()
  Dim Oo As OLEObject
  Dim wDoc As Object 'Word.Document

  'Search for the embedded Word document
  For Each Oo In Worksheets("Input").OLEObjects
      If InStr(1, Oo.progID, "Word.Document", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
          'Open the embedded document
          Oo.Verb xlVerbPrimary
          'Get the document inside
          Set wDoc = Oo.Object

          'Copy the contents to cell A1
          wDoc.Content.Copy
          Worksheets("Paste").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
```

Comment: Where's the rest of the code, mainly the closing `End If // Next Oo`?

Comment: Comments ruined the paste, the rest of the code is copying and pasting the cells from "InputPaste" into a template in another sheet. Cut down to side to save people eyes.

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613) You need to tell us what is going wrong, where you got errors or stuck exactly and what you expect instead of the actual behavior. Also you should correct your code (especially your comments, which should start with an `'` instead of `//`). You might also read how to provide an [mcve]. Also a screenshot might help us.

Comment: @peh The question is extremely clear "how to prevent excel from splitting paragraphed text?" It's a common problem.

Comment: Basically the text you're copying has CRLF in the string and you want to avoid Excel interpreting that as multiple cells.

Answer (score 1):

The text you're copying has CRLF in the string and you want to avoid Excel interpreting that as multiple cells.

Just avoid using Paste and use Range.Value instead. Problem solved.

```
'Search for the embedded Word document
For Each Oo In Worksheets("Input").OLEObjects
If InStr(1, Oo.progID, "Word.Document", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    'Open the embedded document
    Oo.Verb xlVerbPrimary
    'Get the document inside
    Set wDoc = Oo.Object

    'Copy the contents to cell A1
    Worksheets("Paste").Range("A1").value = wDoc.Content
```

This will put the entire wDoc.content into one cell. That's not what you really want though. You really need to loop through the table in Word and use `.Value` to insert the data into Excel.